# use mp4parser to edit the mp4boxes

Tags: java, android, mp4box

Can some one give me a guide on how to use mp4parser to edit the mp4boxes?

I tried

```
MP4Edit edit = new MP4Edit();
edit.open(inputFile);
edit.editBox("moov", newBoxContents);
edit.close();
```

but I want the detailed solution for all the boxes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.